# Way to track users between apps?

Tags: ios

Let's say I have 3 apps, how can I track users between those apps? I want to see if a user in one app has downloaded a second app of mine and combine that data on the backend. I know I could ask for some sort of identifier (email, phone, etc.), but how can I do that without doing that? I don't think I am allowed to use the IDFA for this, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should do is check to see if any of your other apps are installed. You should give your apps a custom URL scheme (as posted by @mika) so they can be found. Then check to see if the app exists on the device by checking:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:yourCustomURLScheme])
```

To share the data between the apps, configure an app group for your apps.

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html):

> Use app groups to allow multiple apps access to shared containers and
>   allow additional interprocess communication between apps. To enable
>   app groups, in the Capabilities pane, click the switch in the App
>   Groups section. You can select existing app groups from the table or
>   add app groups.

I believe that this would be a simple way of "tracking" them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Custom URL Scheme to find out what of your apps were installed by a user. 
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
Then you can flag you tracking data accordingly.

Comment: It seems like that will open the app, right? I want it to work in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics can be configured to share tracking between apps.   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en

Comment: He doesn't want to share tracking between apps, he wants to track and share data based on conclusions made from the tracking data (if that makes sense).